# disable/remove auto increment attribute in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, auto-increment, alter

the table i used is ,

`create or replace table abc(id int autoincrement, name varchar,date_of_birth date, age number, ts timestamp_ntz);`

I used the below query to remove auto increment attribute in snowflake

`alter table abc modify id int`

here i have redefined the column name without the auto increment attribute . it works fine in mysql workbench but it is not working in snowflake .
is there is some other way to disable/remove auto increment attribute in snowflake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Drop default" is doing the trick:

```
alter table abc alter id drop default;
```